# Proposal to revert CW status on the "universal float" question

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-wiki

I propose that the CW status of the question:

[How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

be reversed (I'm informed that this can be done).

I can understand the decision to make it CW as it appeared to be asking for a list of answers and these are traditionally CW.  However, I think that it has developed in a different direction and that if considered now then it might not be made CW.  Please note that it can always be made CW again at a later date, and that individual answers can be made CW independently of the question (though if the question is CW all (subsequent?) answers become CW).

My reasoning is the following:

1. Although the question seems to be looking for a "big list" and certainly didn't take much "research" on behalf of the questioner(!), this could well be one of the most **useful** questions on the site (note that I didn't say *popular*, I don't care about that) and although I wouldn't want copy-cat questions, I would want questions that could be similarly useful.
2. Frank's answer is looking as though it is going to be the Ultimate Treatise on floats.  Again, this kind of answer should be treasured on the site and I think that forcing it to be CW is, in some circles, seen as a "it's okay but on the borderline".  It's not about the reputation (either real or imaginary) but about the perception of this question-and-answer and its status on our site.
3. I suspect that there was an expectation of this being "use package X" or "use package Y".  It's not clear yet how comprehensive Frank's answer will be, but I can envision a situation where Frank's answer *explains* everything but doesn't necessarily say which package is best for *achieving* a particular behaviour.  So there is scope for others to answer, but once Frank's answer is finished then I doubt that anyone will just say, "Use package X"!  I expect that people will raise their game and say a longer version of "If you want to do what Frank describes *here* then use package *X* in *such and such* a way" with nice examples and so forth.

As this is a proposal, it seems reasonable for people to be able to vote and to put counter arguments.  I think that the *answers* to this "question" should be used for opinions and so forth.  I'll put two *comments* to this "question" which can be voted upon to gauge opinion (note that votes can only be cast "upwards" and cannot be rescinded).

Comment: The question in question should remain Community Wiki.

Comment: The question in question should not be Community Wiki.

Comment: I think the answer of Frank shouldn't be a CW because he honores the reputation.

Comment: woah ... amazing what is happening behind the scene ... so this is how it became an non comunity wiki again - still a long way to the ultimate answer though ... but I'm working on it ;-) there must be some trick on how to keep better track of what is happening on the site ... or are you guys really scanning it constantly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This all seems pretty clear: I will undo the CW. I've also forced a rep recalculation for Frank, Marco and wh1t3, so there is no need to unvote/revote on anything